# Какой условие проверки нужно написать для определения title на странице товаров?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть каталог продуктов(магазин), в нем товары, при клике на товар открывается страница с товаром. Шаблон для страницы вывода всех товаров(магазин) и конкретного товара один и тот же. Какую проверку написать, чтобы определяло title страницы? К примеру если мы на главной странице товаров, то не выводит ничего, а если переходим на конкретный товар, то отображало title товара.
Title для товара в бд есть. Адресная строка выглядит таким образом: для магазина 
 - 127.0.0.1:8000/shop  , для конкретного товара - 127.0.0.1:8000/shop/{slug}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну смотри. В главном шаблоне, то есть `index.blade.php`, там где title страницы пишешь `@yield('title','Главная страница')`(второй параметр необязателен, он показывает какой тайтл у главной страницы. А в дочерних уже определяешь секцию этого тайтла, типа `@section('title') Имя товара или значение из бд @endsection`. Надеюсь нормально объяснил)

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось. Я просто начал думать не про тот метод, но этот гораздо проще)